# apply a condition in html based on a boundfield

Tags: html, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview and a command field that is a link to a page. How can I replace the link with just text based upon an field in the record?

Here is the code:

```
<asp:CommandField SelectText="View" ShowSelectButton="True">
                        <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
                    </asp:CommandField>
```

So I want to replace the CommandField with "N/A" for a record that meets a criteria of Date<2015. Where Date is a field in the record.
Thank you.

Comment: The code didn't show with the question...                       <asp:CommandField SelectText="View" ShowSelectButton="True">
                            <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
                        </asp:CommandField>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is task worth a custom template field. I'd suggest to have both controls in the template, and show either one or the other based on your condition. Something like this:

```
<TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal Text="N/A" runat="server" Visible='<%# ((DateTime)Eval("FieldName")).Year < 2015 %>'>
        <asp:Button Text="View" CommandName="Select" runat="server" Visible='<%# (int)Eval("FieldName") >= 2015 %>'>
    </ItemTemplate>
</TemplateField>
```

So as you can see the literal with N/A text and the button basically alternate visibility based on the condition.

Comment: Andrei, that you for your help. I now get Specified cast is not valid. error. I am returning a datatype of int for the year. Any thoughts?

Comment: @JRasmus, sure, just cast result of eval to int. For some reason I assumed it is a DateTime field. See the edit

Comment: Andrei, here is the line of code:<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" Text="N/A" runat="server" Visible='<%# (int)Eval("EYear") < 2015 %>'/>

Comment: Andrei, Thank you again for your help.  Here is the line of code:<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" Text="N/A" runat="server" Visible='<%# (int)Eval("EYear") < 2015 %>'/> and I still get 'Specified cast is not valid.' error. EYear is an int from sql. Anything else?

Comment: Andrei, here is what I ended up with. In SQL I returned a T or F if year was less then 2015. The html code worked out to this  Visible='<%# Eval("EYear").ToString() == "T" %>'. Thank you again.